# Why does xargs xargs execute what xargs would have printed to the screen?

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

From what I understand, the xargs command in Linux can be used to take the output of one command and pass it in as input for another command. However, I noticed that passing xargs as an argument to itself executes what previously would have simply been the output had it been called without parameters and defaulted to echo. My question is why calling xargs as an argument to itself execute the output?

```
$ echo ls | xargs

ls

$ echo ls | xargs xargs
AppData
'Application Data'
centos-7.box
Contacts
Cookies
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Dropbox
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `echo foo` prints `foo`.
- So, `echo foo | xargs bar` runs `bar foo` with no input; it's equivalent to `bar foo </dev/null`.
- So, `echo ls | xargs xargs` runs `xargs ls` with no input; it's equivalent to `xargs ls </dev/null`.
- `xargs ls` with no input runs `ls` once.

In the future, you might find it helpful to use the `-t` flag to `xargs`, which prints the command before running it:

```
$ echo foo | xargs -t xargs -t
xargs -t foo 
foo 
xargs: foo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.